# My for loop is slowing down my timer. How to fix?

Tags: c#, for-loop, timer

I'm creating mini-game where spaceship need to avoid meteorites.I have two timers one to create shower and second for moving meteor. First timer on tick(2000) has this code:

```
    int pozicija = rnd.Next(1, 26);
    pozicija *= 30;
    meteor[i] = new PictureBox()
        {
            BackColor = Color.Transparent,
            Size = new Size(30, 30),
            Location = new Point(pozicija, 0),
            Image = imageList2.Images[0],
        };
    this.Controls.Add(meteor[i]);
    i++;
```

that create random meteor falling and that works. But i have one more timer that on tick(1) move meteor to bottom of form, and i used this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            meteor[j].Top += 5;
            if (meteor[j].Location.Y == 800)
            {
                meteor[j].Controls.Remove(meteor[i]);
                meteor[j].Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Here i add 5px to top of my meteor object, and i dispose of meteorites if they fall. After every meteorite that is created all of them move slower than they should. 
I also declered pictureBox array as global and random number also.
Can someone offer me a solution to this or why this happened? If you need to visual this form here you have img.[image]

Comment: IIRC there are 10 ticks in a millisecond, this would be too fast

Comment: @dlatikay What do you suggest, how can i solve this?:D

Comment: so many possibilities... 1) stop the timer inside its tick handler and restart it once it has completed all of its tasks; 2) increase the interval of the 1-tick timer by a factor 100 3) make the transition from a picturebox-based approach to a frame redrawing game loop.

Comment: I highly recommend not using a timer for a game loop. You should just have a loop that runs the game, to make it consistent you check the time each iteration and sleep on a the consistent value.  If your loop slows down then your game slows down but your sleep never happens or sleeps less...  There's probably a book of words to say about that but overall, avoid the timers is my advice before finding bottlenecks.

Comment: Try to avoid using controls and moving them. Instead, use one `PictureBox` and draw shapes in it using `Graphics`. This is extremely faster solution.